# SharePoint 2010 Configuration Wizard error step 2 of 10 on Windows 7

Tags: configuration, configuration-wizard, standalone

Following are the error details from the log file

1. The ServerBindings or SecureBindings property was not found for IIS schema IIsWebServer
2. An exception of type System.InvalidOperationException was thrown.  Additional exception information: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object. 
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.WebSiteCollection.GetServerBindings(PropertyCollection properties, Boolean& secure, String& ip, Int32& port, String& host)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.PostSetupConfiguration.WebSiteCollection.TryGetIisMetaData(DirectoryEntry entry)
3. Failed to retrieve the server bindings with an internal InvalidOperationException
4. Failed to successfully retrieve iis meta data, so we will skip this website entry

Comment: Did you install this hotfix?
http://support.microsoft.com/KB/976462
Is your machine sysprepped btw? Because I've seen similar errors related to that. In addition, does the account you're logged on with has the right permissions?

Comment: not installed any hotfix..But I am logged in with administrator account which has all right permissions. but still i am facing this error.

Comment: I would install the hotfix. Did you have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869(v=office.14).aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485(v=office.14).aspx? There are specific sections on Windows 7 and a standalone install.

Answer (score 1):

the problem was with my SharePoint source with SP2 in it. uninstalling and installing from another SP1 source resolved my problem

also uninstalling Office 2013 resolved 3 of my problems

- creating new web application
- breakpoints does not hit in debugging mode
- config wizard does not complete successfully

[SharePoint 2010 Configuration Wizard error step 2 of 10 on Windows 7](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/53331/sharepoint-2010-configuration-wizard-error-step-2-of-10-on-windows-7/133663#133663)